# Sending JSON Object in a python Request with SSL pfx certificate attached

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I'm trying to send a JSON object to an API using the requests.post method with a SSL certificate in pfx format attached.
And I keep getting this error from the server, I don't think the JSON object is poorly constructed:

> "status":"401",
> "message":"
> {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Not valid credentials supplied. Please check request parameters."}"

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import json
import requests
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import Encoding, PrivateFormat, NoEncryption
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.pkcs12 import load_key_and_certificates

cert_file = "certificado/cert.pfx"
cert_password = "xxxxx"
    
    

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json'
}


@contextmanager
def pfx_to_pem(pfx_path, pfx_password):
    ''' Decrypts the .pfx file to be used with requests. '''
    pfx = Path(pfx_path).read_bytes()
    private_key, main_cert, add_certs = load_key_and_certificates(pfx, pfx_password.encode('utf-8'), None)
    
    with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.pem', delete=False) as t_pem:
        with open(t_pem.name, 'wb') as f_pem:
            f_pem.write(private_key.private_bytes(Encoding.PEM, PrivateFormat.PKCS8, NoEncryption()))
            f_pem.write(main_cert.public_bytes(Encoding.PEM))
            for ca in add_certs:
                f_pem.write(ca.public_bytes(Encoding.PEM))
        yield t_pem.name


jsonObj = {"Things to send"}
myURL = "https://myurl.com"

with pfx_to_pem(cert_file, cert_password) as cert:
    response = requests.post(myURL, json=jsonObj, cert=cert, headers= headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        response= json.loads(response.text)
        print("Response OK!")
        print(response)
         
    else:
        print(response.status_code, response.text)
```

Comment: Have you inspected the generated `.pem` file (using e.g. the `openssl` command)?

Comment: I also forget to say, that this code works for get requests but the same doesn't appen for post requests

Comment: I generate a cert.pem and a key.key with openssl and I changed the cert parameter input with "cert=("/file/path/certificado/cert.pem", "/file/path/certificado/key.key")" but it stil works with get requests but not with post requests.  Note that the .pem file is not empty